# How to show a category name even when there is no post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to show WordPress Category name in my Taxonomy page, but every time that Category has no **post**, its name won't be show. How can I show it, even when it's empty?

```
<?php

 $term = get_queried_object();
 $term->slug;
 $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'productcat');
 $nameTerm = $terms[0]->name;
 $linkTerm = get_term_link($terms[0]);

?>

<span><?php echo $nameTerm ?></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get all terms of the category, not just the post terms. Use `get_terms`. You can pass `hide_empty` to show the categories that don’t have posts.

```
<?php
 $term = get_queried_object();
 $term->slug;
 $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
 ) );
 $nameTerm = $terms[0]->name;
 $linkTerm = get_term_link($terms[0]);
?>
<span><?php echo $nameTerm ?></span>
```

Comment: Always make sure there is no more than one `if(count($terms) > 1) `

Answer (score 2):

```
 // Prior to WordPress 4.5.0

      $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
          'hide_empty' => false,
     ) );

 // Since WordPress 4.5.0

      $terms = get_terms( array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'hide_empty' => false,
     ) );
```

In this context, you may check this code

```
  $taxonomy_text = "";
  $cat_list = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product_cat', '<strong>In this post:</strong> ', ', ', '' );

  if ( '' != $cat_list ) {
        $taxonomy_text .= "$cat_list<br />\n";
  }
```